# Image uploading in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, image, image-uploading, laravel-5.8

I am a beginner in laravel. i need to upload an image and that image needs to saved in the database but it is not working Could somebody take a look at my logic and see where I'm going wrong?

> StudentController.php

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateRequest();

        // Handle File Upload
        if($request->hasFile('cover_image')){
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);

        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }

        dd( $fileNameToStore);

        $student = new student();

         $student->cover_image = $fileNameToStore;

         $student->save();

        return redirect()->route('show')->with('response', 'Registered Successfully');                
    }
```

when dd( $fileNameToStore); it is giving the result as "noimage.jpg"

> create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
 {!! Form::open(['url' => 'student','method' => 'get', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'])!!}

<div class="form-group">
   {{Form::file('cover_image')}}
</div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}

</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Are you sure if the method of form is get ?? You must change it to post